# How to make a function get called faster

Tags: javascript, function

I am making a game of pong and want I have a working function that moves the paddles up and down. I want to call this function more often than it is called. The paddles move much too slowly and I don't want to increase the amount they move each time the function is called because that makes it "choppy"

I have tried to use a set interval but to no luck I just got an error.

```
document.body.addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
    getWasdKey(e);
});

function getWasdKey(e){
  var key = e.keyCode;
  if(key == 119){//w key
    leftUp();//up
  }
  if(key == 115){//s key
    leftDown();//down
  }
  if(key == 107){//k key
    rightUp();//up
  }
  if(key == 109){//m key
    rightDown();//down
  }
}

var x = 1;
function leftUp(){
  setStyle('paddlewasd', 'top', (parseInt(getStyle('paddlewasd', 'top'))) - x + "px");
}
function leftDown(){
  setStyle('paddlewasd', 'top', (parseInt(getStyle('paddlewasd', 'top'))) + x + "px");
}
function rightUp(){
  setStyle('paddlearrow', 'top', (parseInt(getStyle('paddlearrow', 'top'))) - x + "px");
}
function rightDown(){
  setStyle('paddlearrow', 'top', (parseInt(getStyle('paddlearrow', 'top'))) + x + "px");
}
```

As a side note, I created a setStyle function to help make my code work better. It works properly and has before. It takes 3 parameters, id, css property, and what you want to set it to. Get style is just the first 2 parameters.[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvQyV.png) [Game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itvWn.png)

Comment: `setInterval` will call the function implicitly after regular intervals ,I guess that's not the process you are looking for ,as you are capturing keypress events.

Comment: The keypress event only happens so often. What you could do is running an interval when the key is pressed and cancel this interval when the key is is not pressed and use this interval to set the style.

Comment: I would recommend you modify the `transform` property instead of `top`. Every time you change `top`, the browser will have to reflow the document, which leads to slow and laggy animations. If you use `transform` with `translate3d` instead, your movement will be much smoother.

Answer (score 1):

You are currently relying on the keyboards repeat frequency, which can differ on different systems.

I would recommend that instead of listening for keypress events, you create a game loop using [request​Animation​Frame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame), and in that loop you inspect the keyboards current state and react accordingly.

EDIT: Here's a minimalistic example demonstrating how you could do this

```
const keyState = {};

window.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
  keyState[e.keyCode] = true;
});

window.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
  keyState[e.keyCode] = false;
});

function frameLoop () {
  requestAnimationFrame(frameLoop);

  if (keyState[KEYCODE]) {
    // Do something
  }
}

requestAnimationFrame(frameLoop);
```